# You would say that sam has run/ran/had run a red light

Tags: tense, reported-speech, conditionals

John: What does "running a red light" mean?

(1) Sam: *If I were to drive past a red traffic light without stopping, you would say, "Sam **has run** a red light".*

(2) Sam: *If I were to drive past a red traffic light without stopping, you would say **that** Sam **has run/ran/had run** a red light.*

Is the verb tense in (1) correct? Which tense should I use in (2)?

Comment: There's no reason why the response in the first (direct speech) context shouldn't be *"Sam **ran** a red light",* but the way you've presented the question implies you think use of Simple Past is somehow affected by whether it's reported speech or not. Come to that, *in appropriate contexts* the other person might use ***Past*** Perfect rather than Simple Past or Present Perfect. The choice of verb tense here has nothing to do with direct or reported speech - it's entirely a matter of the speaker's context, and the implication he might wish to make.

Comment: Both item 1 and item 2 refer to the same event and are worded exactly the same.  Why would they be different?  The quoted text uses the same tenses whether presented as a direct quote or otherwise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Canonical Post #2: What is the perfect, and how should I use it?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it)

Comment: Please fix your question title.

Comment: @EllieK, Inside the quotation marks we have a **real** sentence/construction using real verb tense, while, outside we have a **hypothetical** construction. My question is if I remove the quotation marks, would the verb tense in the that-clause get affected? Because as far as I remember, we tend to backshift verbs in hypothetical constructions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, so depending on the speaker's context etc, would you say all the verb tenses in the OP are equally possible?

Comment: They're not "equally" possible. For example, contexts where someone might say *"Sam had run a red light"* are relatively uncommon. They'd have to *already* be talking about some time in the past, *after the running of the light*, in order to use Past Perfect to refer to "the past within the past". For example. *"We were stopped by a police car last night. **Sam had run a red light,** but they let us off with a warning"* would be fine, because running the red light came *before* being stopped by the police.

Comment: But certainly all combinations of Simple Past, Present Perfect, and Past Perfect are perfectly valid *syntactically*, regardless of whether they're used in "direct quoted" speech (he said *"**I am Sam**"*), or "indirect reported" speech (he said *[that] **he was Sam***).

Comment: Note that your context could equally well start with Simple Past instead of "subjunctive", as *If I **drove** past a red traffic light...* Some people will say Simple Present *If I **drive** past a red traffic light...* should only pair with *...you **will** say...,* but lots of native speakers don't care about such nitpicking details. All permutations do in fact occur, even if pedants don't like certain combinations.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, what I understood from your comments is that the verb tense of the sentence inside the quotation marks depends entirely on the context. Also, if we remove the quotation marks, and use a that-clause instead, the verb tense is not going to change. It will remain the same, even if it's a subordinate clause of a hypothetical construction. It's just **unlike** the normal direct/indirect speech: *he said "**I am Sam**"; he said [that] **he was Sam**.*

Comment: Therefore we can say: *you would say "sam **ran** a red light".* = *you would say that sam **ran** a red light*. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I think you may have been misled by the concept of ***backshifting*** when a speaker is reporting *what someone else said **in the past***. As in my example above, where it's unlikely that Sam would ever have actually said the exact words *"I was Sam"* - but we usually backshift that as *He said [that] he was Sam"*. Not the same context as your example ***IF** (conditional / unreal **future**).*

Comment: Your dramatic scenarios do not provide nearly enough information to define a context,  to make a choice possible.